# How can I reference a website outside of localhost? Apache wants to find /website.com on the server

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I'm developing on my localhost and I want to display an `<iframe>` for debugging reasons, but Apache keep searching the directory for the source I provide the Iframe.

PHP:

```
echo "<iframe src= http://newyork.craigslist.com</frame>"
```

results in:

> The requested URL /newyork.craigslist.org was not found on this
>   server.

How do I specify that the target URL is not on the server?

Comment: in addition to the answers about missing quotes and stuff, your closing tag should be `</iframe>` to match the opening tag

Answer (score 1):

Use valid HTML.

```
echo '<iframe src="http://newyork.craigslist.com"></frame>';
```

If you decide to use double quotes `"` for your string literals, make sure to escape the attribute quotes with `\`.

Comment: My real code was some hacked up version of what I posted and I got caught up with "\"" trying to backslash out of the other quotes. Thanks for the idea of using single quotes for string and double as the raw character.

Comment: @Brian If your using a backslash, you will need to escape said slash by using  two backslashes `\\\`

Comment: @DarylGill, Only if he wants a literal backslash \.  At least in his example, that isn't needed?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove blank space between `src=` and `http://`, and add `>` before `</frame>`:

```
echo "<iframe src='http://newyork.craigslist.com'></frame>"
```

Comment: you didn't mention the missing quotes

Comment: It was not that important in this example, but in case of more complex URLs missing quotes may cause problems, so it is better to use them as well.